# Report Formula Issue: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to group donations into groups based on the donation close date/time in a Salesforce report.

The formula I wrote is:

```
IF(Opportunity.Close_Date_Time__c<=2022-09-02 14:00:00,"Group 1","Group 2")
```

When I validate the formula, I get the error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective the problem is here - Opportunity.Close_Date_Time__c<=2022-09-02 14:00:00. You should use DATETIMEVALUE to get value from string.
Could you please try this:

```
IF(Opportunity.Close_Date_Time__c<=DATETIMEVALUE("2022-09-02 14:00:00"),"Group 1","Group 2")
```